# How to get browsing history for PC in same network

Tags: networking, security

I have made a ticket booking recently without creating an account from my office network. After few days, I receive an email saying that my ticket has been cancelled. When I contacted the flight, they could just tell me the IP address of my ISP. We are using static IP address. I wanted to know which PC has cancelled my ticket. Is there any way to know from which IP address has the ticket been cancelled?? Please help me..!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, this question is to broad in content for anyone to help you. There is no way we can help you with what little detail you have given. It might be of benefit to read [ask] in the [help], then update your question.

Comment: Ask your IT department if they can help?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but barring exceptional circumstances (e.g. entire harddisk of every PC is network shared with unrestricted access), there is no (legal) way you could access the browser history of other PCs in the network that I am aware of.

May I suggest a social approach (e.g. posting on the bulletin board in the cafeteria) to solve this issue?

Comment: What would be "illegal" about accessing other computers' data on his company's private network?

Comment: As I said, if the data is made available to you (e.g. per network share) there's nothing illegal in it.
But if it's not, then you need illegal activities like hacking other employees accounts or the like.

If OP were the owner of the company, that'd be another story.

Comment: @snejjj: And David Postill suggested "Ask your IT department if they can help" in a comment on the question, and Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 is pointing out that it is quite normal (***not*** "exceptional") for the company's IT department to have the right to examine the computers that are company property.

Comment: @G-Man yes, you're right, the IT department could possibly do that, but in my experience, IT won't give away information from other PCs freely to anyone that asks. They could get in serious trouble for that if someone higher up the food chain finds out.

btw, is there a reason why most answers are given in the comments section instead of as answers?